# Save location of user markers in google maps javascript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markers

I'm working on a map that I'd like users to be able to add markers to. Specifically, I'd like a way to save the markers they add so that any time the map is reloaded you can see where others have placed their markers. Is this possible? I feel like I've scavenged the internet quite a bit and can't seem to find a way to do it. I'm very new to development and have never used google's API before, so I may be asking for something that's impossible.

http://test-bd8a1b.webflow.io/

the map I'm working on is here.

Comment: Not without some kind of database, whether it be a simple JSON storage mechanism or a relational/nosql database.

Comment: One option is to use Firebase to store marker locations. Take a look at the [Collaborative Realtime Mapping with Firebase Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/firebase). It has sections on "setting up Firebase" and "storing click data in Firebase" that you might find helpful.

Answer (score -2):

you can add event listener to map on every marker creation and save the latitude and longitude into array or you can save them to database. Later you can show them on map.

```
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
           -- write code to save markers details into an array
         });
```

Comment: You're right that the event listener will have to be on the map but in your code you put `marker.addListener`.